# Problem with passing input to std::cin during debugging C++ in VSCode

Tags: c++, debugging, input, visual-studio-code

Type: Debugger

- OS: Windows 10
- VS Code Version: 1.42.1
- C/C++ Extension Version: 0.26.3
- No other extensions installed
- A clear and concise description of what the bug is:
  The main issue that I have is the inability to **pass input to std::cin** using VSCode debugging tool for C++. I tried different things that I found online, the main one was enabling `"externalConsole":true` in the `launch.json`, but in vain. In fact, when I do that, an external console appears, but it seems 'bugged', since it has a blinking cursor, but when I write into it, nothing happens.

Here is a screenshot of the 'bugged' external console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkrT6.jpg

Here is my `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code sample that I am trying to execute:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you always had this problem with `cin`? When was the last time `cin`worked in VS?

Comment: Actually `cin` works fine in 'normal' mode (without the debugging tool). The problem occurs when I use the debugging tool.

Comment: That's maddening. I'd just aim to reinstall and hope that fixes it.

Comment: I'll consider that as a last option. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do "***externalConsole***":true in the ***launch.json*** under the ***.vscode*** in your working directory. 
After that an external Terminal Window will appear, enter the input after you hit STEP OVER while on CIN!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I just needed to step over in VSCode debug interface so that the external console let me write in it.